# If $A \in \sigma$-algebra, is it true that $A \subset \Omega$?

Tags: measure-theory

In the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. $\mathcal{F}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. By definition, $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$.

This is my reasoning:

If $A \in \mathcal{F}$, $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq \Omega$ then $A^c \neq \emptyset$, $A^c \neq \Omega$ and $A^c \in \mathcal{F}$ so the complement of $A$ exists, then it follows that for any set $A$ in $\mathcal{F}$ it is true that $A \subset \Omega$.

Am I right?

Comment: By definition, $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of subsets of $\Omega$, so...?

Comment: hi @gogurt I forgot the definition, so I wanted to prove it!

Comment: You wanted to *prove a definition*?

Comment: @gogurt I re-read the definition of sigma-algebra and I found out I totally forgot that part, that any set in a sigma-algebra is a subset of $\Omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitions cannot be proved, since they are not claims of any kind. Rather, they are simply meanings behind particular terminology.

In this instance, when we say "$\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega,$" we mean that $\mathcal F$ is a set with the following properties:

- $\Omega\in\mathcal F,$
- for all $A\in\mathcal F,$ we have $A\subseteq\Omega,$
- for all $A\in\mathcal F,$ we have $\Omega\smallsetminus A\in\mathcal F,$ and
- for any countable collection of subsets $A_1,A_2,\dots$ of $\Omega,$ we have $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in\mathcal F.$$

Now, we can prove that two apparently distinct definitions are equivalent (in the sense that one is satisfied if and only if the other one is), and we can prove that a given definition is satisfied in a particular situation, but we can't prove a definition to be true.

nother way to think about this: a definition uniquely determines the collection of all things that satisfy the definition. How can we prove that a collection of objects is true?

Comment: After thinking and rethinking I found that my mistake came from forgetting your second point of the sigma-algebra definition